# cannot underustand django custom authenticaton backend

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users, django-login

I am trying to learn from book django 3 by example but i cannot understand few points in django custom authentication like  why username and password is passed None and email=username
and why we are using get_user

Here is the code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class EmailAuthBackend(object):
     #Authenticate using an e-mail address
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None):
        try:
            user=User.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            return None
        except User.DoesNotExit:
            return None
    def get_user(self,user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExit:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None):
```

`username` and `password` are None by default, this is done to make sure if user didn't send any `username` or `password` here, it will be `None` by default. Otherwise if user didn't send here any `username` or `password`, and there will be no default variable statement, it will return error, that `this variable doesn't exist`

actually here if you will remove assining to default statment by None, nothing will change, it will work the same, because if user wouldn't send `username` or `password`, `try` will work the same way
so this is actually equal to:

```
def authenticate(self,request,username,password):
```

(but with default statements it is considered safer)

this line:

```
def get_user(self,user_id):
```

is a handy method to get particular `User` object, you'll meet this method a lot. This is just trying to find `User` object in database, if it finds User, it will `return this user object`, if it doesn't find User object, it will `return None`

But in this particular part of code `get_user` method isn't used

Comment: and why we use email=username

Comment: @shafquetNaghmi in `User` model by defualt you must use `username` and `password` fields, but sometimes in your project's you have not `username` but you have users `email` so in this case you can make `username` = `email` and it should work, i believe this is the case here